# PHP CURL Fatal error: Call to a member function getAttribute() on null

Tags: php, curl

For some reason I am getting the following error when there is no image on the url being called in the functions.

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getAttribute() on null in .... on line 29
```

This doesn't happen if their is no title, it doesn't happen if there are no meta tags, and it doesn't happen if their is no paragraph tag. It only seems to happen when there is no img tag. How can I make this work so that when there is no image it stops spitting out an error.

```
<?
function file_get_contents_curl($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    return $data;
}

function getit($site) {

    $parsing = file_get_contents_curl($site);
    //parsing begins here:
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    @$doc->loadHTML($parsing);

    $nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title');
    $node = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
    $para = $doc->getElementsByTagName('p');
    //get and display what you need:

    $title = $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $firstimage = $node->item(0)->getAttribute('src');
    $firstparagraph = $para->item(0)->nodeValue;

    $metas = $doc->getElementsByTagName('meta');

    for ($i = 0; $i < $metas->length; $i++)
    {
        $meta = $metas->item($i);
        if($meta->getAttribute('property') == 'og:description') {
            $description = $meta->getAttribute('content'); } 
        elseif ($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'description') { 
            $description = $meta->getAttribute('content'); } 
        else { $descrition = "<p>".implode(' ', array_slice(explode(' ', $firstparagraph), 0, 25))."</p>"; }
        if($meta->getAttribute('property') == 'og:image') {
            $image = $meta->getAttribute('content');
        }   
    } 

    if ($image != '') { $image = $image; } else { $image = $firstimage; }

    $str .= 'Title: '.$title.' <br/><br/>';
    $str .= 'Description: '.$description.' <br/><br/>';
    $str .= 'Image: <img src="'.$image.'"><br/><br/>';
    echo $str;
}
?>
```

Comment: for the sake of portability, security, and god knows what else, stop using short tags!

Comment: I have no understand what you mean @hanshenrik. None of the code posted above uses any short tags. Are you specifically referring to the use of <? ?> or are you see something more?

Comment: yes i mean those <? ?>'s. they're bad for a bunch of different reasons. for instance, they won't work on servers where short tags are disabled. if you move to a new server where they're disabled, and you have any hardcoded passwords, others may be able to see your source code, and your hardcoded passwords. and they make it more error prone to run XML files through the parser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this check before getting attrib:

```
    if($node->item(0)->hasAttribute('src')) {
       $firstimage = $node->item(0)->getAttribute('src');
    } else {
      $firstimage = "";
    }
```